Cucumber jvm 7 and maven: Running tests from command line
I've got a Java project set up with Selenium and Cucumber for end-to-end testing. Since I'm also using the not-allways-so-stable IDE IntelliJ, I'm dependent on the option to run tests  with Maven from the command line, for stability etc.
So, normally I run the whole test suite like this:
mvn -U clean install --quiet -P e2e

This works fine. All the Selenium tests are run.
But, my tests are also labeled with tags, as well as the scenario names. So I'd also like the option to run either single named scenarios, or tests with specific labels.
And that's where I'm struggling.
If I try this to run tests with a named label
mvn clean install -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Temp"

the build process finishes sucessfully, but no tests are run at all.
The same goes if I try to use scenario name:
mvn clean install -Dcucumber.options="--name 'scenario name'"

Using "mvn test" is equally bereft of results:
mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Temp"
mvn tet -Dcucumber.options="--name 'scenario name'"

Any ideas?
UPDATE:
Trying as per the suggested answer below:
$ pwd
/home/me/hofh/Skrivebord/repos/startlan-esoknad

Find the path for the feature file(s):
$ ls startlan-esoknad-backend/startlan-esoknad-selenium/src/test/resources/features/arbeidsflate/arbeidsflate.feature
startlan-esoknad-backend/startlan-esoknad-selenium/src/test/resources/features/arbeidsflate/arbeidsflate.feature

Trying to run the feature:
We use the following to run the whole e2e-test quie (skipping the api and unit tests):
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests
So, trying this:
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dcucumber.features=startlan-esoknad-backend/startlan-esoknad-selenium/src/test/resources/features/arbeidsflate/arbeidsflate.feature

and
mvn clean install -Dcucumber.features=startlan-esoknad-backend/startlan-esoknad-selenium/src/test/resources/features/arbeidsflate/arbeidsflate.feature

Doesn't work.
Trying the example suggested below:
mvn test -Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber -Dcucumber.plugin=pretty -Dcucumber.features=startlan-esoknad-backend/startlan-esoknad-selenium/src/test/resources/features/arbeidsflate/arbeidsflate.feature

Doesn't work either. It just builds, and no Selenium tests are run.
(also tried adding ":line number" after the ".feature", for the line number where the Scenario starts. Same results.)

Please include your POM file.

Also cucumber.options has been removed. See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-core#properties-environment-variables-system-options

Exactly what in the .pom file? The whole file is way too big to post.

@kakemonsteret The declarations regarding your tests in <project><dependencyManagement>, <project><dependencies>, <project><build><plugins>, including those in <parent>(s) if there is/are any.

I posted the whole file here: https://pastebin.com/1Fc8dQAg

@kakemonsteret usually you would make an example project that is small enough to share. For tips see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

And are you on Windows using CMD by any chance? If so, then your shell has different quoting rules I.e. -D"cucumber.feature=path/to/example.feature".

The same goes for all other options btw. When using Powershell or CMD or any everything after the -D should be quoted.

@M.P.Korstanje I'm on Linux.

Not a clue then. You'll have to work this out by yourself mostly. One way would be to try to reproduce the problem a much smaller project.

See Cucumber-Java Skeleton:

Running a single scenario or feature
Maven and Gradle do not (yet) support selecting single features or scenarios with JUnit selectors. As a work around the cucumber.features property can be used. Because this property will cause Cucumber to ignore any other selectors from JUnit it is prudent to only execute the Cucumber engine.
With Maven
To select the scenario on line 3 of the belly.feature file use:
./mvnw test -Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber -Dcucumber.plugin=pretty -Dcucumber.features=src/test/resources/io/cucumber/skeleton/belly.feature:3
Note: Add -Dcucumber.plugin=pretty to get test reports. Maven does not report tests without a class.


This is correct. Assuming the cucumber-junit-platform-engine is used.

Please see my updates. Can't get this to work with "-Dcucumber.features".

"This is correct. Assuming the cucumber-junit-platform-engine is used" Not sure if it is, but the exact line doesn't exist in the project.
